# Regex separate binary operators

Tags: regex, token

I need to divide tokens: `= == <= >= < >` and `~=` neatly in separate regexes. Currently I have:

```
(=)    for = 
[=]{2} for == 
(<=)   for <=
(<)    for <
(>=)   for >=
(>)    for >
\~=    for ~=
```

but i am afraid these will interfere with each other (`=` cant match the equal sign in e.g. `<=`)

Any recommendations?
I am new to regex so if you have an answer please explain a bit :-)

Comment: Alternation listing most specific to least specific: `(abc|ab|a)` matches abc *or* ab *or* a ...

Comment: They will not interfere. If you specific a capturing group such as `(<=)`, it __must__ match all values inside that aren't specified as optional and therefore will not match `=` or `>=` or `~=` etc...

Comment: but `(=)` & `(<=)` would both match `"a <= b"` which is his concern I think

Comment: but i mean that = will match <= for example, or will it automatically pick <= since its the longest match?

Comment: The rule for any regex engine is that the leftmost match wins. In an alternation `a|b|c...`,  for backtracking regex engines, the first branch that succeeds wins, for posix regex engines (sed, grep...) the longest match in the alternation wins.

Comment: you need a single **regex** to match all you want? Am I right?

Comment: Na, i still want them separated, answer is below though :) @k-five

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kinda depends on your environment and regex engine! If it is a DFA or POSIX NFA engine, then you are always going to match the **longest**, **left-most** possible pattern. You can determine if your engine works this way by trying to match

```
nfa|nfa not
```

against the string "nfa not". If the entire string matches, then you know you're working with a longest, left-most engine, ie. DFA or POSIX NFA.

However, the most common engine type is Traditional NFA, where you are granted a lot of expressive power and control with your regexes but, as usual, that power comes with responsibility. In a traditional NFA, longest left-most is not guaranteed. I will explain Alex K's abc|ab|a solution. The '|' (called OR or alternation) is a way of saying match abc OR ab. You may wonder, "what if the text is 'abc'? Either one works in that case!". That is true! And in a traditional NFA, the options are tried from left to right. So in a traditional NFA, searching for ab|abc in the text "abc" will match "ab" and searching abc|ab will match the whole "abc". You can take advantage of this by searching for <=|= in your text to ensure you always get '<=' rather than just the '='.

It turns out that Alex K's solution will work regardless of engine because '<=' is also the longest, left-most match. I thought I'd give a deeper explanation to provide some understanding and maybe arouse your interest. Check out 'Mastering Regular Expressions' by J. Friedl if you want to learn more!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Before i got "rule can not be matched" but when i read this i realized i had to put them in a different order. since i want them separated (GT, GTEQ, LT etc.) i just put them in order: [=]{2} (<=) 
(>=) 
\~= 
(>)
(<)
(=)